# Can not installing "Karma-Cli" in Windows 8.1?

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

I can't install Karma-cli in Windows 8.1. 
Afer running setup procedure in my terminal:

```
npm install -g karma-cli
```

I have some errors:

```
npm WARN engine karma-cli@0.0.4: wanted: {"node":"~0.8 || ~0.10"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
C:\Users\Marcona\AppData\Roaming\npm\karma -> C:\Users\Marcona\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma-cli\bin\karma
karma-cli@0.0.4 C:\Users\Marcona\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma-cli
└── resolve@0.5.1
```

**How I can fix this errors?**

*P.S. If I right understand, this error has, because I have Node version == 0.12.0, so how I can decrease versionof NodeJS?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only running a single instance of node, you'll have to uninstall version 12 and install an earlier version that is compatible.

If that's the case, you should probably look into a node version manager that works on Windows.  Tools like [nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist) or [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) let you install multiple versions and switch between them as needed while you develop and test.

Once you uninstall version 12, install a version manager first and then re-install the versions you need to do your work.